# Show dialog from service

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm creating a voip app and when a call comes in I need to alert the user so they can accept or reject the call. I want a dialog like what hangouts uses:

[image]

I've tried using an alert dialog with type TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT. However there are issues with this:

- It requires ugly system permissions. (takes you to a full screen activity to accept overlay permissions)
- It displays centered vertically not at the top over the top bar.
- Any time anyone asks about this online everyone says your shouldn't be doing it this way, but doesn't tell you how to actually do it.

I didn't have to accept any overlay system permissions on my hangouts so how does google do it?

What is the correct way to display a dialog to the user from a service to accept a call?

Comment: "I want a dialog like what hangouts uses" -- that is a heads-up notification, not a dialog, from the looks of it. "What is the correct way to display a dialog to the user from a service to accept a call?" -- use a heads-up notification. If you truly want a dialog, your `Service` needs to start a dialog-themed activity.

Comment: Thanks, +CommonsWare I'm not hung up on what it's called I just need to know how to do it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up

Comment: Two issues with heads up notification, 1. They timeout after about 5 seconds, can't find out how to make them longer. 2. Android 5 and newer, but we need to support android 4.4.4